# Read Stata 13 file in R

Tags: r, stata

Is there a way to read a Stata version 13 dataset file in R?

I have tried to do the following:

```
> library(foreign)
> data = read.dta("TEAdataSTATA.dta")
```

However, I got an error:

> Error in read.dta("TEAdataSTATA.dta") :
>   not a Stata version 5-12 .dta file

Could someone point out if there is a way to fix this?

Comment: Not within the `foreign` package. `?read.dta`: " Frozen: will not support Stata formats after 12".

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks Ben, is there something that does it for a Stata 13 file (by the way, i think your father is Ben Bolker, he taught me math a long time ago :) , sorry if this is strange )

Comment: you mean Ethan Bolker, right?  Don't know, sorry -- probably someone would have to sit down and reverse-engineer the format.  http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-10/msg00701.html comments that transfer to SPSS is hard now, too.

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Stata-support-in-package-foreign-td4684022.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have Stata 13, then you can load it there and save it as a Stata 12 format using the command `saveold` (see `help saveold`). Afterwards, take it to R.

If you have, Stata 10 - 12, you can use the user-written command `use13`, (by Sergiy Radyakin) to load it and save it there; then to R. You can install `use13` running `ssc install use13`.

Details can be found at http://radyakin.org/transfer/use13/use13.htm

Other alternatives, still with Stata, involve exporting the Stata format to something else that R will read, e.g. text-based files. See `help export` within Stata.

### Update

Starting Stata 14, `saveold` has a `version()` option, allowing one to save  in Stata .dta formats as old as Stata 11.

Comment: Ok thanks a million. But sorry I still have one problem, when I try to write to convert the data to an spss file, I type: Suppose I have imported the data from the STATA file to a data frame called `data1`, then I write the data frame to a text file using `write.table(data , 'mydata.txt' , sep="\t")` and then to get the SPSS file I do: `write.foreign(b , "mydata.txt" , "DerLeew.sps" , package="SPSS")` but I get error: `Error in writeForeignSPSS(df = list(studyid = c("P0008", "P0018", "P0031",  : 
  I cannot abbreviate the variable names to eight or fewer letters`, thanks.

Comment: I can't say why. My knowledge of R is more limited. I do wonder what's going on with all those conversions: Stata to R to txt to SPSS. If you want to convert Stata to SPSS, try the Stata command `savespss`, again by Sergiy Radyakin. Read the following to get started: http://www.radyakin.org/transfer/savespss/savespss.htm.

Comment: wouldn't I have to use Stat/Transfer to do it directly in STATA?

Comment: Not at all. Sergiy has made a great effort on the issue of data transfer. All you need to do is install that command with `net from http://radyakin.org/transfer/savespss/beta` and read the web page in my previous comment to learn the (very simple) syntax. (By the way, the spelling is Stata, not STATA. It's not an acronym. )

Answer (score 96):

There is a new package to import Stata 13 files into a data.frame in R.

Install the package and read a Stata 13 dataset with read.dta13():

```
install.packages("readstata13")

library(readstata13)
dat <- read.dta13("TEAdataSTATA.dta")
```

**Update**: readstata13 imports in version 0.8 also files from Stata 6 to 14

More about the package: https://github.com/sjewo/readstata13

Comment: I get `Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘httr’` when attempting to execute the `devtools::install_github("sjewo/readstata13", ref="0.2")` line.

Comment: Hi Dan! Your devtools is probably outdatet and the httr package is missing. Try to update your packages    `install.packages("devtools", dependencies=T)`    and check if you can load devtools with     `library(devtools)`    . Maybe you could also check for httr with     `library(httr)`    .

Comment: What does your package do with any `strL` variables in the dataset?

Comment: strL variables inherit a refer to a string in a list obtained by `attr(NameOfDataset, "strl")` .

Comment: In version 0.4 the option `replace.strl=TRUE` can be set to replace the reference to a `strL` string in the data.frame with the actual value.

Comment: Adding that by my benchmark, `readstata13` is faster, albeit on a very small data set (420 obs  x 12 var); not sure how it scales up so I'm not adding it to the answer

Answer (score 29):

There's a new package called Haven, by Hadley Wickham, which can load Stata 13 dta files (as well as SAS and SPSS files)

```
library(haven) # haven package now available on cran
df <- read_dta('c:/somefile.dta')
```

See: https://github.com/hadley/haven

Comment: Just a head's up that `haven` did not seem to be as accurate as `readstata13` as far as formatting, marking many numerical variables as character variables. So that may be something to consider for those using `haven`.

Comment: +1 because `haven` is also the best-suited, I've found, for importing other proprietary formats like `.sas7bdat` from SAS, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006822/read-sas-sas7bdat-data-into-r), whereas `readstata13` is clearly a single-purpose package.

Comment: FYI, `haven` is now available on CRAN. No need to install from github.

Answer (score 6):

In the meanwhile **savespss** command became a member of the SSC archive and can be installed to Stata with: `findit savespss`

The homepage http://www.radyakin.org/transfer/savespss/savespss.htm continues to work, but the program should be installed from the SSC now, *not* from the beta location.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with the current state of R programs regarding their ability
to read other file formats, but if someone doesn't have Stata installed on their computer and R cannot read a specific version of Stata's `dta` files, `Pandas` in Python can now do the vast majority of such conversions.

Basically, the data from the `dta` file are first loaded using the [`pandas.read_stata`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_stata.html) function. As of version `0.23.0`, the supported encoding and formats can be found in a [related answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50472355/8682794).

Then one can either save the data as a `csv` file and import them
using standard R functions, or instead use the [`pandas.DataFrame.to_feather`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_feather.html) function, which exports the data using a serialization format built on Apache Arrow. The latter has extensive support in R as it was conceived to [promote interoperability](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/) with `Pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Tried `read.dta13`, `read.dta` but nothing worked. Then tried the easiest and least expected: MS Excel! It opened marvelously. I saved it as a `.csv` and used in R!!! Hope this helps!!!!