# pandas and Stata 13 files

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I have pandas 0.13.1 installed but `pandas.read_stata()` fails to read **.dta** files created in Stata 13 format, with the error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

No problem at all with the same dataset saved in Stata 12 format.

I thought that the latest release of pandas (0.13.1) handled Stata 13 dataset files. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you're not doing anything inherently wrong, but that your version of pandas can't handle Stata 13 dataset files. As documented in [help dta](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?dta), the format of Stata .dta datasets changed with the release of Stata 13.

**Solution 1.**

Update your pandas to v0.14.0 (May 31 , 2014):

> read_stata now accepts Stata 13 format (GH4291)

Source: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html

**Solution 2.**

If you have access to Stata, there are several ways of reverting to earlier/different formats that should work with your earlier version of pandas. See this answer:

[Read Stata 13 file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899009/read-stata-file-in-r/23899204#23899204)

### Edit

**Solution 3.**

After some discussion in [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7360]) the problem pandas seems to have with Stata 13 datasets are *string* variables. So another solution could be converting the string to numeric type. See `help encode`, which will create appropiate value labels; or maybe `help real` or `help destring`, if the strings happen to be just numbers in string type.

Comment: Thanks Roberto. Solution 1: Stata 13 files still do not work with pandas v0.14.0 I am afraid, at least on my system. Solution 2: yes that's what exactly what I do; simply save datasets under Stata 12 format ("saveold" in Stata) - these are correctly read by pandas.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. I've reported it here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7360.