# Export Stata regression result to R?

Tags: r, stata

My colleague and I chose Stata for regression analysis due to good handling of survey data. We also want to use R for graphics, but do not know how to export Stata regression model.

Within Stata, of course there is `return list` and `ereturn list`. But what's the best way to export these results outside of Stata? Direct to R would be ideal, but any intermediate format would be fine as well.

Comment: Stata output is just a text log file, so I think you should consider doing your survey regressions in R using the `survey` package. I will write an example below.

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/svy_r_regest.htm

Comment: @Carl Thanks for the suggestion! In your experience does R `survey` give identical result as Stata? My co-author only knows Stata, so he would be skeptical and unwilling to read R code...

Comment: I have never run direct Stata to R survey comparisons, but I have run R survey to SAS survey comparisons. In general point estimates are identical and SEs vary slightly, but not too significantly. Note: my comparisons only used replicate weights.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "exporting Stata regression results". Stata is a professional statistical environment, and although I accept R can make for really impressive graphs, Stata has an ample repertoire of professional-looking graphs. Is there some specific reason for wanting to produce graphs in R,  given that the analysis is done in Stata?

Comment: "Exporting Stata regression result" means exporting the coefficients, the standard error, the t-statistic, etc. in such a manner that can be imported into other programs (R in this case). I think the reason for exporting in my case is simply that I'm much more competent with R graphics. I've also seen papers using both R and Stata (judging from graph and table style), so I'm curious how it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to do this, I would create a Stata dataset with all the regression results using [postfile](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/ppostfile.pdf). Then import it into R using, for example, some technique from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899009/read-stata-13-file-in-r/23899204#23899204). Manipulate within R at your convenience.

See also the user-written command `rsource`: `ssc describe rsource`.

Disclaimer: my knowledge of R is rather limited.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise using regsave

```
ssc install regsave
```

E.g. after a regression command you could use

```
regsave, tstat pval ci
```

to replace the current dataset by the estimation results and save it afterwards.