# Reading Stata 14 file in R

Tags: r, stata

I have tried a thousand different times to read a `Stata14` file on `R`, and for some reason I keep getting weird things happening (like variables dropped and such.)

The original file is saved in `Stata 13` or `14`, so the `read.dta()` command does not work. I also tried `read.dta13()` and it reads it sometimes but it cuts off the database at a certain spot and does not give me all the variables contained in the data set (which I can see and work with perfectly on Stata). The original file can be found [here](http://datasets.americasbarometer.org/database-login/usersearch.php?year=2014) and scrolling down to `Uruguay`.

Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this issue? I am tired of arguing with `R` to read my `Stata` file correctly, when it works perfectly in `Stata`.

Comment: Why not load into STATA and outsheet as a CSV.  Or use saveold in STATA

Comment: Can you tell us what precisely you've tried?  Have you tried with a recent/development version of the [haven package](https://github.com/hadley/haven/) ?

Comment: @JacobH I tried saveold and to save it in Stata12 and it still is not working... R reads part of the data base, but not all of it. R is not reading part of the variables that I need.

Comment: @BenBolker I have tried read.dta(), read.dta13(), saveold in Stata to save into an older format. I have also downloaded the database in SPSS and the same issue happens -- R only reads it partially and drops some variables. Haven't tried the haven package, but will do it now and report back the results of my attempt.

Comment: Then try `outsheet` in STATA.  This will allow you to transform the data to a .CSV.  You can then read into R.

Comment: The dataset aren't version Stata 13 or 14 files, but version 12 and below (I saw one file saved in Stata 8). I could read the files without problems with read.dta13.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know this is an old thread but every time I google "read stata 14 with R" I come to this unresolved answer.

Community on SO have answered this: [Read Stata 13 file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899009/read-stata-13-file-in-r)

As of today, there is a CRAN package to read stata 13 and 14 using this:

```
install.packages("readstata13")

library(readstata13)
dat <- read.dta13("myStataFile.dta")
```

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 19):

Have a look at Hadley's `haven` package ([CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/index.html), [github](https://github.com/hadley/haven)). It:

> Works with Stata 13 and 14 files (foreign only works up to Stata 12).
>
> Can also write SPSS and Stata files (This is hard to test so if you
>   run into any problems, please let me know).

Once installed you simply:

```
read_dta("path/to/file")
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of forcing other packages to read your data, you should convert your data to a common format such as **CSV** or Excel sheet **XLS** or **XLSX**. Stata allows you to create a decent text data set that is highly portable in almost any version of any statistics software.

To do so, go to **file** -> **Export** or just use `export delimited`or `export excel` respectively.  for more details type `help export` in your Stata command line.

You can also downgrade your data to Stata 12, or even Stata 11 by using the **saveold** command:

```
saveold "name.dta", version(11)
```

This command will create the oldest dataset that can be created in Stata 14. This probably would solve your problem, but still, I recommend using the **CSV** format. It's just how it works when transferring data between different software.

Comment: I don't think users should be required to have the original software installed. I cannot buy SPSS if someone sends me a SPSS file. Data files should be easy to convert *to* the software researchers use. (R allows for that, curiously Stata does that only to a limited degree, and refers to an expensive software called Stat/Transfer.)

Answer (score 0):

To convert too modern Stata data into the older version (say 14 into 13), the following code could help you:

```
write_dta(Data, "Path, version = 13, label = attr(data, "label"))
```