# R and Stata performing differently with large datasets

Tags: r, out-of-memory, stata

I have a dataset with 40,000,000 observations and 23 variables. It is written is Stata format (.dta) and 4.4 Gb large.
Stata opens the file in circa 30 seconds, while R is not able to do it and reports the error term:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 201.8 Mb
```

In R I have used the `haven::read_dta` function without any extra argument.
The Windows file manager reports 30% RAM usage when the file is open in Stata, and 96% when R attempts to do the same.

Why this big discrepancy in performance between the two software?

I am using a machine with Windows 10 64-bit, 16gb RAM and an Intel i7 8th gen.

Comment: Try using `library(readstata13)`, another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820594/r-how-to-quickly-read-large-dta-files-without-ram-limitations) references this as being a faster way to read large files.