# I have a .dta file which has variable labels for each variable. Once imported to R, how can I view these labels?

Tags: r, file-import, dta

I imported a .dta (Stata file format) into R, but it looks like the variable labels did not get imported along with the variable names.

- Using `foreign::read.dta`, I tried `labels(df)`, but that only gives me the variable names; and `str(df$var)` is also is not telling me label.
- Using a function from the `haven` package, `attributes(df$var)` gives me levels and class, but not variable label.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Per `haven` [docs](https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/read_dta.html) (assuming this is your package), *Variable labels are stored in the "label" attribute of each variable*. Check: `attributes(df$col1)`.

Comment: If Parfait's pointer doesn't resolve it, you may need to add more information (like the tool you used for import, maybe the Stata version). You could also try `str(DF)` to look around for the labels more.

Comment: Does that help https://stackoverflow.com/a/25850262/5784831?

Comment: @parfait - I just tried the `haven` package and `attributes(df$var)`, which gives me levels and class, but not variable label.

Comment: @Frank - I also tried `str(df$var)` and that also is not telling me label. I'm guess the labels must not have transferred over, so I should probably try a difference import function? I used `read.dta()` to import.

Comment: First, it's useful to state that .dat is a Stata file format; 99% of users won't know - I added that in body and tags. Second, I believe you're talking about making sure **categorical labels** get imported right, right? Can you narrow the issue down to whether they're getting correctly **exported from Stata to the .dta file** (can you show us a snippet of .dta file?), or **imported from .dta file to R**?

Comment: Yeah, it might be that a different function is required, or you could try changing the arguments to the R function (from Parfait's link, maybe you think the file is from one version, but it's really from another?). Both foreign and haven are kept up to date, so I'd expect them to somehow work. As smci noted, it might also be a problem with the export from Stata (testable by reopening it there, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

To see variable labels in R, it depends on how the Stata file is imported. Just using the `foreign` package (command `read.dta`) does not import variable labels.

Use the `haven` package to import the Stata file (`read_dta` command). Using the `attributes` command via `haven` package (@parfait) will give you format, class, and levels, in addition to variable label. However, if you only want to see the variable labels, then use the `var_lab` command from the `expss` package.

```
    library(haven)
    df <- read_dta(file="df.dta")
    library(expss)
    lapply(df, var_lab)
    # OR
    var_lab(df$var)
```